# How do i suppress exponential display output

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulty to format a simply float column in a dataframe:

```
output_df['ann_avg_prem'].map('${:,.2}'.format)
```

I would like output that resembles:

```
0 $1,650.00
1 $1,650.00
```

But for some reason, I cannot suppress the exponential notation.  I would like to maintain space in my presentation output for up to $99,999,999.99.

Here is what I am getting instead:

```
0    $ 1.6e+03
1    $ 1.6e+03
2    $ 1.6e+03
3    $ 1.6e+03
4    $ 1.6e+03
Name
e: ann_avg_prem, dtype: object
```

I seriously cannot make any sense of the documentation for formatting, and everything I am trying is giving me an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Add `f` specifier:

```
 df.x.map('${:,.2f}'.format)
 #               ^ this
```

Output:

```
0    $1,650.00
1    $1,650.00
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: One letter...so much frustration!  Thanks so much!